# Logging in with Facebook and Linkedin is inconsistent

Tags: ruby-on-rails, facebook, heroku, linkedin-api, omniauth

I am working on a Rails application that uses omniauth facebook and linkedin login. It's been working for months, and today we are suddenly having crazy problems logging in / signing up on production (Heroku). I assumed that the problem was on our end, but we have not pushed new code to production in 4 days.

After hours of trial and error, we realized that about half of the time, we are able to login, maybe another 40% of the time we are redirected to the sign in page from linkedin / facebook, and the rest of the time we get an application error with elastic search that I assume results from the insanely long load time. Additionally, when the app renders the login page, in the logs there are "expired token" type errors, which is weird because sometimes it actually works.

I'm assuming that Facebook and Linkedin are not both broken. Does anyone have any feedback on other points of failure that I might look into.

Answer (score 0):

Well, restarting the dyno seems to have fixed the problem.